# Azure Pipelines - proper way to use Poetry

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

what would be a recommended way to install your Python's package dependencies with `poetry` for Azure Pipelines? I see people only downloading `poetry` through `pip` which is a big no-no.

```yaml
- script: |
    python -m pip install -U pip
    pip install poetry
    poetry install
  displayName: Install dependencies
```

I can use curl to download `poetry`.

```yaml
  - script: |
      curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
      export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.poetry/bin
      poetry install --no-root
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
```

But then in each subsequent step I have to add poetry to `PATH` again ...

```yaml
  - script: |
      curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
      export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.poetry/bin
      poetry install --no-root
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'

  - script: |
      # export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.poetry/bin
      poetry run flake8 src
    displayName: 'Linter'

  - script: |
      # export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.poetry/bin
      poetry add pytest-azurepipelines
      poetry run pytest src
    displayName: 'Tests'
```

Is there any **right** way to use poetry in Azure Pipelines?

Comment: What is the agent you are using, Microsoft-host agent or self-host agent?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT
How would it be relevant?

Comment: The difference is if you are using a Microsoft-host agent, installing packages every time will be necessary because poetry is not supported in any version of Microsoft-host agent and azure DevOps will assign a random Azure VM for every time you run the pipeline. But if you use a Self-host agent, you just need to prepare any package you need in advance, and then you can run your pipeline in this environment

Comment: "If you are installing poetry on an ephemeral CI environment or in a container, installing to the system-site [via pip] might cause minimal side-effects and should be okay." https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/3946

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consulted this issue with a collegue. He recommended doing separate step to add Poetry to the PATH.

```yaml
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8'
    displayName: 'Use Python 3.8'

  - script: |
      curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
      export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.poetry/bin
      poetry install --no-root
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'

  - script: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$HOME/.poetry/bin"
    displayName: Add poetry to PATH

  - script: |
      poetry run flake8 src
    displayName: 'Linter'

  - script: |
      poetry add pytest-azurepipelines
      poetry run pytest src
    displayName: 'Tests'
```

Comment: This code failed for me.

Comment: This seems to only work for windows VM image.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this accepted answer it will not work until you update the curl command to get the latest poetry which is: "curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -"
For more info see the poetry installation instructions: https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain this is a best practice, but Azure build agents do have pipx installed, and this is [a supported way to install Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-pipx). It does still require an install every time, but you can't avoid that without self hosting.

I did try using Poetry and it seems to work as I'd expect. It creates a separate virtual environment for Poetry and then you can use it as you wish. Caveat here is I'm no Poetry or Python deployment expert.

Answer (score 0):

The following `azure-pipelines.yml` works like a charm for me:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  pythonVersion: '3.9'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'

- script: pip install poetry
  displayName: 'Install poetry'

- script: poetry install
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: poetry run ruff check
  displayName: 'Run linter'

- script: poetry run pytest -s
  displayName: 'Run tests'
```

Answer (score -1):

From your description, I think the agent you are using is a Microsoft agent?

I checked the official document of the Microsoft agent, there is no poetry provided. Therefore, if you use Microsoft-host agent and you want to use poetry, install poetry during the pipeline run is inevitable

So I recommend you run your pipeline on a self-host agent.

You can use a VM or your local machine which already has the poetry and then set up a self-host agent on it.

After that, you can run your pipeline on it, this time you don't need to install the poetry anymore.

Detailed steps:

**1, run the below command on a VM or local machine.**

`pip install poetry`

**2, Install configure, and run the agent in above VM or machine.**

On my side, I set up an agent on VM:

[image]

Please refer to this official document, this document will tell you how to install and run the self-host agent on your side:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

**3, Run your pipeline based on the agent that ran above.**

```
pool:
  name: VMAS
steps:
- script: |
   echo Write your commands here
   
   echo Hello world
   
   python --version
   
   poetry --version
   
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

Then you don't need to install it every time.
[image]

Let me know if you have more concerns.

Comment: This question wasn't really about the agent but the recommended way to use `poetry` inside the pipeline. Your answer suggests installing `poetry` with `pip` which is a dangerous thing to do.